# Play youtube video inside tableviewCell using 'YoutubePlayer Swift SDK'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, youtube

I am integrating 'YouTubePlayer Swift SDK'
You can check in this link [Swift-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player)

All things working properly, but I face one issue i.e
When I playing video, I always played in fullScreen. I want to play video inside tableviewCell only like we can see in Facebook, Instagram.

Same thing is possible in 'youtube-ios-player-helper SDK' by assigning playerVars.
Like this,

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                          @"playsinline"    : @1
                        };
```

Is there anyOne who having idea to play videos in swift?
Please share code if possible

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: add some additional code'

Comment: @Anbu.karthik
There is not much code need to do,
at mySide I only load video url like this

cell.vwPlayer.loadVideoID("vTRAUjImBFQ")

apart from this all this done by swift SDK

Comment: youtube-ios-player only plays in the particular frame not in the full screeen, check once your cell.vwPlayer frame,

Comment: But I need it only in swift, objc lib not working in my swift code

Comment: ok let me check by putting ObjC library manually

Comment: problem not in the libray

Comment: Yes there are 2 different libraries for youtube player>> for swift using Swift-YouTube-Player and for Objc using youtube-ios-player

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167808/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-anjali-jariwala).

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got solution by spending 4 Hours :)

If you guys need to get SDK work same as objc Specially for parameters

Please go to 'YouTubePlayer.swift' file which inside your sdk
and just replace 'serializedJSON' function with this:

```
fileprivate func serializedJSON(_ object: AnyObject) -> String? {

    var dict = object as! NSDictionary
    var dictTemp = dict.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
    var dictTempPlayerVar = dictTemp.value(forKey: "playerVars") as! NSDictionary
    var dictTempPlayerVar1 = dictTempPlayerVar.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
    dictTempPlayerVar1.setValue("1", forKey: "playsinline")
    dictTemp.setValue(dictTempPlayerVar1, forKey: "playerVars")

    do {
        // Serialize to JSON string
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictTemp as! AnyObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        // Succeeded
        return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? String

    } catch let jsonError {

        // JSON serialization failed
        print(jsonError)
        printLog("Error parsing JSON")

        return nil
    }
}
```

It works :)